Interpretation of self-interacting terms in the expansion of a pure YM Lagrangian?
Let $A^{\alpha}_\mu$ be the gauge field of a Yang-Mills theory where $\alpha$ is the gauge index of generators for some Lie algebra with structure constant $C_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma$ and $\mu$ is the space-time index.
According to Wiki article, the field strength tensor is given by
\begin{equation}
F^\alpha_{\mu \nu}:=\partial_\mu A^\alpha_\nu - \partial_\nu A^\alpha_\mu + C_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma A^\alpha_\mu A^\beta_\nu
\end{equation}
and the Lagrangian is
\begin{equation}
L_{YM} := F^{\alpha \mu \nu} F^\alpha_{\mu \nu} \text{ up to an overall normalization factor }
\end{equation}
Now, expanding every term in the above $L_{YM}$, we roughly have
\begin{equation}
L_{YM} \simeq (\partial_\mu A_\nu^\alpha)^2 - \Bigl[C_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma A^\alpha_\mu A^\beta_\nu\partial_\mu A^\gamma_\nu \Big] + \Bigl[ C_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma C_{\alpha' \beta'}^\gamma A^\alpha_\mu A^\beta_\nu  A^{\alpha' \mu} A^{\beta' \nu} \Bigr]
\end{equation}
where I have omitted numerical factors in each term.
Obviously the first term $(\partial_\mu A_\nu^\alpha)^2$ can be interpreted as the "free theory part". On the other hands, the two terms in $[ \cdots]$ are "self-interacting parts" Moreover, the third term in $L_{YM}$ above looks like a "quartic" interaction.
Now my question is that

What sort of interaction does the second term $-C_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma A^\alpha_\mu A^\beta_\nu\partial_\mu A^\gamma_\nu$ stand for? Is it some sort of "cubic" interaction because there are only three factors of $A$? However, presence of the derivative $\partial_\mu$ seems to complicate things...

Could anyone please clarify for me?

I don't know what sort of answer you are looking for. Yes, it's a cubic interaction with a derivative. What specifically do you want to know about this? Also, why does the presence of a derivative complicate things for you? That is a very standard type of interaction term.

@Prahar Sorry for being rather vague... My understanding is that a "cubic" interaction is not physically plausible because there is no stable vacuum. I wonder if this issue applies to the above interaction term. If not, exactly what difference does the presence of a derivative make here?

Let's try a simpler example where you might worry about a cubic. Consider the Lagrangian $L=\frac12(\dot{A}+CA^2)^2$ with momentum $\dot{A}+CA^2$ and Hamiltonian $H=\frac12(p-CA^2)^2+\frac12C^2A^4$. There's nothing unstable about that.

@J.G. How does the Hamiltonian have $C^2 A^4$ term as an extra? How exactly did you perform the Legendre transform?

@Keith - There is no such statement that theories with cubic interactions are unstable. This is something you have to analyze case-by-case. For example, the theory with interaction $L_{int} = ( \phi + \phi^2)^2$ is completely stable even though it has a cubic interaction term.

@Prahar Yes, now I understand. What I originally thought is a theory whose interaction is given by a "single" cubic term.

@Prahar Did you mean $L_\text{int}=(\dot{\phi}+\phi^2)^2$?

@Keith since $L=\frac12p^2$ with $p=\dot{A}+CA^2$, $H+L=p\dot{A}=p^2-CA^2p$ so $H=\frac12p^2-CA^2p$. Now complete the square.

@J.G. Oh, thank you for your clarification. I see that such a choice of $p$ corresponds to the field strength tensor $F$ in my post. Did you choose such $p$ for some sort of gauge invariance?

I derived $p$ from $p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}$ with $L$ as I defined in my first comment mentioning it. Note $F$ is actually analogous to $\dot{A}$. It's not a perfect analogy to field theory because an antisymmetric tensor requires multiple dimensions, i.e. field theory rather than discrete mechanics. But the main point here is that the resulting Hamiltonian is lower-bounded because the momentum isn't just a derivative. In jargon, the canonical momentum isn't the same as the kinetic momentum.

@J.G. - No, I meant what I wrote.

@Keith - Precisely! The same is true for YM. It doesn't have a cubic term by itself. There's also the quartic term, which makes everything nice and stable.

@J.G. The analogy is not perfect, I agree. Still, what I roughly understand is that $F$ is analogous not to $\dot{A}$ but to $p$. So, you are right after all that the canonical momentum (=$p$ or $F$) is different from the kinetic momentum (= $\dot{A}$ or spacetime derivatives of $A$ in general).

Sorry: you're right, an interacting $F$ is analogous to $p$, whereas it would just be $\dot{A}$ in the case of Maxwell's equations.

For what it's worth, if one calculates the symmetric SEM tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ of the Yang-Mills (YM) theory with a compact gauge group $G$, one may check that the 00-component $T^{00}$ (=the energy-density) is non-negative, i.e. the energy spectrum is bounded from below, i.e. YM theory has a stable vacuum, even if this is not immediately apparent from the form of the cubic and quartic interaction terms in the action.

What you explained applies for both quantum and classical theories?

Well I guess I asked quite a trivial question with the above comment. Thank you!
